# How can a forumula be converterd to array formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

How can you convert these to array formula?

```
=IF(COUNTIF($I:$I, $A:A)=0, "No", "Yes")
```

and

```
=CONCATENATE(C3," ",D3)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A&I1:I), IF(A1:A=I1:I, "yes", "no"), ))
```

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C3:C&D3:D), C3:C&" "&D3:D, ))
```